Zonal Statistics as table not working in modelbuilder
When I use zonal statistics as table outside the model builder it works, but using it inside the model resulted in error.
I tried to simplify the model( making new one contain only the zonal statistics tool and it’s input layers but same error occurs



Hi, can you also include the settings you used, and maybe your version of Arcmap?

Is your zonal layer (Un_Bui_Plt) in the same coordinate system as your LSA.tif?

@ChloeG Hi the version is ArcMap 10.8.2. What settings exactly do u need ?

@Hornbydd yes they are

OK two other things to check: does the zonal layer actual intersect the extent of your raster, i.e. they spatially overlap? Is your zonal layer smaller than the resolution of the raster? It often helps with these sorts of questions you actually show your data along with the model. Edit your question to include this extra information.

hi, yes, the layers are spatially overlapped,
for the resolution, the LSA cell size is (12.5), however the zonal layer (Un_Bui_Plt) is shapefile, I am not sure how to check the resolution of the shape file, but here what I did, I converted it to raster then check it's cell size it is (8). @Hornbydd

Ok try converting to a raster and setting the environment setting cellsize to 12.5 so it matches. I would also have snap raster set to lsa.

I tried this, same result.

Then you need to share your data so people can try and replicate the issue and track down whats going on.

First thing I do is setting of environment extent. Most common error in my opinion
